# How to autosize TextView in a ConstraintLayout without using autoSizeTextType?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, textview

I have a TextView in my ConstraintLayout and I want the TextView to occupy only its parent width and height (0dp,0dp). I have seen that in small devices if in my ConstraintLayout I have an ImageView or a View with  `android:layout_width="0dp"` `android:layout_height="0dp"` it will respect the constraints and don't be bigger than its parent. But in the case of the TextView it is not working the same as in small devices, although it has the same attributes than the ImageView, the text protrudes from its maximum space. To let you undestrand I am posting an image to let you see how the TextView is protruding out of its constraints:

Image of the problem:
[the text should show Example text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mg5Ox.jpg)

I am not using wrap content because I need the TextView to occupy exactly that squere of space. I think that the problem is that the TextView size doesn't auto-adjust automatically according to the screen size. What could I do so that the size is equal to a size that all the text is perfectly seen?

Also I ahve seen that I could use  `android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"` but I can't as it is needed API level >=26

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:text="@string/example_of_text"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
    android:textColor="@color/txt_light"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/view2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/view3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view4" />
```

I tried to use `android:layout_width="0dp"` `android:layout_height="0dp"` in the TextView as I said using a ConstraintLayout but the text it is overlapping with its constraints.

Edit:

Changed TextView to AppCompatTextView:

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:text="@string/example_of_text"
         android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/txt_light"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/view2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/view3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view4"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform">

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *AppCompatTextView* for autosizing if your minSdk >= 14. According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/text-and-emoji/autosizing-textview):

> The Support Library 26.0 provides full support to the autosizing TextView feature on devices running Android versions prior to Android 8.0 (API level 26). The library provides support to Android 4.0 (API level 14) and higher. The android.support.v4.widget package contains the TextViewCompat class to access features in a backward-compatible fashion.

You would specify `android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"`. `app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"` may also work.

**Update**: Regarding use of *AppCompatTextView* in XML. From the documenation:

> [AppCompatTextView] will automatically be used when you use TextView in your layouts and the top-level activity / dialog is provided by appcompat. You should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views.

Comment: I have implemented AppCompatTextView and noticed that using `android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"` the warning of min API level is shown: "Attribute autoSizeTextType is only used in API level 26 and higher ". In the other hand, using `app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"` is not warning me about min API. Does it mean that if I use AppCompatTextView I can use perfectly `app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"` for autosizing for minSdk >= 14 and it is important that it is used "app:" and not "android" or it is indifferent?

Comment: I have edited the question with the changes I made according to your answer to let you check what I have changed, also I was wondering if I need to add some dependencies of AppCompatTextView in the build.gradle files or no dependencies are needed?

Comment: `app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"` will likely work for all APIs. You could specify both "app" and "android" as the prefix to cover all bases but will need to suppress the error if that is a problem for you.(Add `tools:targetApi="o"`) As for dependencies, see the updated answer.

Comment: what I don't understand is why the warning: "Attribute autoSizeTextType is only used in API level 26 and higher " is shown using `android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"` if supposedly AppCompatTextView will work for autosizing if the minSdk >= 14. Why the warning is shown then? I thought that warning was only being shown using TextView but not using AppCompatTextView...

Comment: For API <26, the attribute "android:autoSizeTextType" doesn't exist - it was introduced in API 26 as a native attribute. The appcompat version of _TextView_ uses its own attribute "app:autoSizeTextType" as its own custom attribute. for API <26. For API 26 and above, it can use either attribute since either may be available to it.

Comment: In short words, if I use AppCompatTextView, "android:autoSizeTextType" will only work with API >=26 and "app:autoSizeTextType" will only work with API >=14. Is this right?

Comment: Yes. That looks right.

Answer (score 0):

You can set unit text size in `dp` instead of `sp`.

```
android:textSize="15dp"
```

Answer (score -2):

android:layout_marginStart="10dp" and Try to use ssp and sdp library.
Give  android:layout_width="0dp" as match_parent